# Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKeys

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am trying to write the logs back to custom table in Log Analytics Workspace-Azure using Automation Runbooks and getting the below error. SPN has contributor access though

Error:
HTTP Status Code: Forbidden
Error Message: The client 'xxxxx' with object id 'xxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/sharedKeys/action' over scope '/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/crdopssbx-Mallik-Test/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/Test-ResourceChanges' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
Request Id: xxxxxx
Timestamp (Utc):11/17/2022 07:15:40
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKeys -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $workspaceName

At the above line, I am getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

> Error Message: The client 'xxxxx' with object id 'xxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/sharedKeys/action' over scope '/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/crdopssbx-Mallik-Test/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/Test-ResourceChanges' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

The above error states that doesn't has permission to Authorize the workspace.

According to this [**MS-Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/services-hub/health/azure-roles#the-following-users-can-create-new-azure-log-analytics-workspace-under-new-resource-group-that-are-linked-to-services-hub-workspace) if you need access the workspace you need either has **`contributor`** or **`owner`** role.

I have a **`contributor`** role in my portal:

[image]

Now I'm tried the same command to get the shared **`OperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKeys`** in my console, I got an successful output.

**Command:**

```
Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKeys -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup name> -Name <workspace name>
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKey (Az.OperationalInsights) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/get-azoperationalinsightsworkspacesharedkey?view=azps-9.1.0)

Comment: @Mallikarjuna Reddy  I agree with Venkatesan. Please check whether the client indicated in your error message has the corresponding permission of your workspace.